# Angular wrapper component iterating over children

Tags: javascript, angular, wrapper, children

I am trying to create a wrapper component in Angular, where the component can receive any number of children, and then wrap each item one by one. Preferably completely dynamically without binding any extra data.

The ***app-wrapper.component*** *should work* like this *(only handles the logic for the wrapper)*:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div 
      class="child-wrapper"
      *ngFor="let child of children"
   >
      <ng-content [select]="child"></ng-content>
   </div>
</div>
```

And using the ***app-wrapper*** *(where the logic is handled for the items)*:

```
<app-wrapper>
   <app-first-item></app-first-item>
   <app-second-item></app-second-item>
   ...
   <app-last-item></app-last-item>
</app-wrapper>
```

> The ***app-wrapper.component*** is not working like this, throws an
>   error:
>
> Error: Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'select' since it isn't a
>   known property of 'ng-content'.

*Please note: The **div.wrapper** and the **div.child-wrapper** can't be separated.*

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Keep trying, you will get it.

Comment: I would look at Dynamic Component Injection. https://medium.com/@tudorgergely/injecting-components-dynamically-in-angular-2-3d36594d49a0

Comment: Please add your code for `app-wrapper.component.ts`. Seems like you're missing an something as easy as an [Input](https://angular.io/api/core/Input)

Answer (score 0):

it seems there are several possibilities to do this.

1/ You can make them into components :

app-wrapper.component :

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div 
    class="child-wrapper"
    *ngFor="let child of children"
   >
    <app-item [item]="child"></app-item>
  </div>
</div>
```

and create ItemComponent with @Input to display an item.

2/ You can create a template reference with ngTemplateOutlet directive
app-wrapper.component :

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <div 
      class="child-wrapper"
      *ngFor="let child of children"
   >
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="test; context: { child: child }"></ng-container>
   </div>
</div>

<ng-template #test let-child="child">
<!-- here an item -->
</ng-template>
```

ng-content is used to inject content inside an element as follows:

in your app-wrapper :

```
<div class="wrapper">
      <ng-content select="[child]"></ng-content>
</div>
```

and when you call your component :

```
  <app-wrapper>
    <div child>element you want to put inside the "ng-content" </div>
 </app-wrapper>
```